# SQL Server: Grouping calculated column results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm a total newbie to SQL Server and was trying to learn by making tasks for myself to solve using Northwind database. I have hit a wall when I was trying to write a query that would result in giving me Net Total Value for whole order.

`dbo.[Order Details]` has three columns that I need to multiply in order to get a total `(Quantity * UnitPrice * (1 - Discount))`. It gives me total value for each product in for the specific `OrderID`. So I get one row for each product in specific order.

This is how it looks like:

```
OrderID     UnitPrice             Quantity Discount      NetTotal
----------- --------------------- -------- ------------- -------------
10248       9,80                  10       0             98
10248       14,00                 12       0             168
10248       34,80                 5        0             174
10249       18,60                 9        0             167,4
```

As you can see every row is one product, I'd love to get one row = one OrderID, like this:

```
OrderID     NetTotal
----------- -------------
10248       266
10249       312
10250       194
```

As you can see every row is one product, I'd love to get one row = one OrderID.
I tried different Grouping methods I found online (Rollup, Grouping Sets and so on), but it didn't work. Could please anyone help me with this task? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT OrderID, SUM(Quantity * UnitPrice * (1-Discount)) AS NetTotal
FROM dbo.[Order Details]
GROUP BY OrderID
```

I hope to be helpful for you :)

Comment: Oh it is just typing mistake. :)